# Is this strategy a Parallel computing or Distributed Computing? MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I have a function to calculate fitness value, say `func()`. In my implementation, I have used MPI for Parallelization.

There are 3 machines in the MPI cluster connected via LAN. These machines are installed with NFS protocol. Memory is not shared among these machines.

The main while loop runs 500 times.

Inside this while loop, I use MPI to parallelize the 9 `func()` calls. Meaning, 9 times `func()` is called inside main while loop, I parallelized that in a way each of 3 nodes gets to call 3 `func()` calls and return the results to the master node.

[MPI Workflow diagram - please refer to this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g13vR.png)
[image]

[What Happens Inside each node please refer this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3iAm.png)
[image]

This continues 500 times in the while loop. (Meaning, in each next loop, again 9 `func()` calls are parallelized)

Is this strategy called a parallel computing or a distributed computing?

Considering the definitions, parallel computing is parallelizing multiple tasks in parallel and distributed computing is distributing a single task on multiple nodes having a common goal. I feel it's parallel computing.

But, here I am executing on different machines, so should I consider it as distributed computing?

Please clear this doubt.

Comment: Without p2p or non-synchronized computations, its still parallel computing. If you use shared+distributed memory model, then its both.

Comment: If I oversimplify, MPI and/or OpenMP are both parallel computing. MPI is distributed computing (but OpenMP is not)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I agree with your comment. But given my scenario, you think it is parallel only right? Can you please add any brief explanation to stand on this ?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik, I feel it has p2p, because I do MPI send, MPI receive functions to send and receive data. Other than this I do not have anything to support it is p2p. 

And non-synchronized, Here the input data, each nodes are reading for its computation is present in all nodes and each nodes are writing to the disk, the output files.  And there is NFS protocol as well.

I am not sure, how to decide on a shared and distributed model. Please let me know how I get this info. 

Considering all these, please let me know if it is parallel or distributed.

Comment: Your program is MPI, so it is both parallel (several tasks collaborate to achieve a goal) **and** distributed (each task has its own memory space, and communicate with other tasks via message - e.g. no shared memory).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I wanted to clarify one point. 

Here each task is not having its own memory. Each node is having its own memory. 

For example, there are 3 nodes, each node does 3 calculations and sends 3 results to every other node. Each node is doing the same task in parallel.

Comment: I meant each MPI task (e.g. Unix process) has its own memory address space. It does not matter here if tasks are running on the same node or on different nodes.

Comment: Okay got it. Can you please confirm again by looking at the work flow diagrams I added in the description now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *distributed computing* to solve a **single problem**, then it is also *parallel computing*. You are using multiple computers (or processors) to solve which satisfies the simple definiton of parallel computing.

> Parallel computing uses two or more processors (cores, computers) in
> combination to solve a single problem.

But, *Not all parallel computing is distributed*. You can perform parallel tasks to solve a problem using shared memory (Using programming models like OpenMP) where you only use a single computer.

Personal Opinion: You can use MPI to solve a problem by using shared memory or in a single computer (without using shared memory) but it remains parallel computing (by broad definition of distributed computing, there should be multiple computers to make it a distributed computing even though MPI has it's own memory space and uses messsage passing)

> A distributed computer system consists of multiple software components
> that are on multiple computers, but run as a single system.

In your case it is both distributed and parallel. As **Gilles Gouaillardet** pointed out in comments:

> Your program is MPI, so it is both parallel (several tasks collaborate
> to achieve a goal) and distributed (each task has its own memory
> space, and communicate with other tasks via message - e.g. no shared
> memory)

Comment: Can you please confirm this by looking at the workflow diagram I added in the description now?

Comment: I just took a look. Yes, it is indeed both parallel and distributed computing.

Comment: I think we should refrain from using programming paradigms such as MPI and OpenMP to differentiate between parallel and distributed computing, because nowadays the borders are really blurred. Modern MPI has explicit support for shared memory while OpenMP supports accelerators and can run on vDSM clusters.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, I agree completely with you. I tried to express that in my answer by mentioning about MPI and shared memory but it didn't come out as expected. :)